# Increments for moving objects gets messed up?

Tags: interface, edit-mode, selection-tools, properties, error

Sometimes when I am in a project, somehow the increments (I guess this is what you call it) for moving objects gets messed up or reversed? Like see here:

This is what normally happens:

[image: Normal moving increments when starting a new project]

This is what happens when it gets glitched (it's like you are holding Control when moving it, but I'm not)

[image: Abnormal moving increments that sometimes happen]

How do I fix this when it happens? I want it to just move like it does by default. If I wanted to move it that way, I would just hold down Control when doing so!

I hope this made sense. Thank you!

Comment: Simple, you probably hit `Shift+Tab` to enable "Snap during transform" (magnet icon on the 3d view menu)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've accidentally enabled Snapping during transform (the little magnet icon) with Increment setting. So it's automatically trying to snap to the "grid" of the world when you move it around.
It's a super handy feature when modeling.

You can read more here [Transform Snapping](https://docs.blender.org/manual/fi/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/snap.html#transform-snapping)

Hope this clears it up. I highly recommend reading up on this feature and playing around with it, it's SUPER useful when polymodeling and moving things around.